# What are the parameters for wordpress register_post action

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin function and the action defined like this:

```
function wp_validate($login, $email, $errors) {

    // do some validations here
    return $errors;
}

add_action('register_post', 'wp_validate', 10, 3);
```

The wp_validate function is called when a user fills up the registration form and submits it.
And the errors are displayed correctly.

But, I don't understand what the 10 and 3 are.
Can someone please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The third argument (`10` in your example) defines the priority your function takes among any others hooked into the `register_post` action.
- The fourth argument (`3` in your example) defines the number of arguments your function accepts.

Both arguments are optional. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action